# Dart PKCS12 p12 pfx generation

Tags: ios, dart, pkcs#12, boringssl

Is there a way in dart to generate a file in the PKCS12 / .p12 / .pfx Format by passing in a Certificate and it's Private Key in pure Dart?

[The BouncyCastle Port has no support for PKCS 12](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle)

For Android, there is the Bouncy Castle Library (Java), I tested it and it works like a charm.

For iOS I find it difficult to build a Plugin with the Open SSL Library linked to it because there is currently no way to tell Xcode to include C Code inside a Flutter Plugin.

dart:ffi would be an option, but it seems like dart has problems with C pointers, so I am not sure how to tackle this.

Comment: I also need to generate a PFX/PKCS#12 file from a PEM certificate file and a key, did you find a solution?

Comment: I used OpenSSL Universal on iOS and Pointycastle on Android.